# Is there any way to unit test es6 modules on NodeJs using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I been looking into this for days and finding nothing useful.

Specifically what I'm *not* looking for is transpiling my source to something other than es6 and testing that instead.

```
// Class1.js

// The use of 'export' makes this an es6 module.
export class Class1 {
   getValue() {
      return 42;
   }
}


// Class1.spec.js

// Jasmine imports its spec files using CommonJS 'require'

// Therefore this import will not work under NodeJs and will fail with the error that
// 'import' cannot be used in a CommonJS module.
import { Class1 } from './Class1';

describe('Class1', function() {
   it('getValue returns 42'), function() {
      let c1 = new Class1();
      expect(c1.getValue()).toBe(42);
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to illustrate your problem? the question is not clear. What do you mean test without transpiling?

Comment: OP updated with an example. To my knowledge that will only run if transpiled with TypeScript or Babel.